# how many different passwords of length 6 or 7 or 8 can be formed?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many different passwords of length 6 or 7 or 8 can be formed?

It should contain only lower case letters and should contain only one digit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the question is asking "or", then we have to add the permutations of passwords for 6,7, and 8 length. So,

$$6\cdot10\cdot {26}^5+7\cdot10\cdot {26}^6+8\cdot10\cdot {26}^7$$

Comment: may i ask you where did the 6 and the 7 and the 8 come from?

Comment: $6\choose 1$, $7\choose 1$, and $8\choose 1$. You are essentially choose the position for the digit.